# Approximate identities and pointwise convergence

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

I'm studying Fourier analysis and learned the concept of approximate identity.

Let $k_{\epsilon}$ be an approximate identity on $L^{1}(\mathbf{T})$. We know that $k_{\epsilon}*f\to f$ in $L^{1}$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Question: Can we construct a $k_{\epsilon}$ such that for every $f\in L^{1}$, $k_{\epsilon}*f$ converges everywhere ?

Comment: Note that function in $L^1$ are only defined almost everywhere. In particular, the convolution $k_{\epsilon} * f$ will forget what $f$ looks like on a set of measure zero. So for this formal reason no. But if you ask that $f$ be a particular continuous or sufficiently differentiable, you may have more luck.

Comment: I don't require $k_{\epsilon}*f$ converges to $f$ pointwise, I just need it converge...

Comment: In what sense of convergence?

Comment: Converge everywhere

Comment: converge everywhere but the limit is not necessarily $f$? that is rather meaningless. Take any $k_\epsilon = k$ which integrates to 1.